# What's the difference between tag and release?

Tags: git, github, tags, github-api, release

Using GitHub's API, I can't get the releases list, but I can get the tags list.

What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 333, accepted):

> What's the difference between them?

A `tag` is a pointer to a specific commit. This pointer can be super charged with some additional information (identity of the creator of the tag, a description, a GPG signature, ...).

A `tag` is a git concept whereas a `Release` is GitHub higher level concept.

As stated in the **[official announcement](https://github.blog/2013-07-02-release-your-software/)** post from the GitHub blog: *"Releases are first-class objects with changelogs and binary assets that present a full project history beyond Git artifacts."*

A `Release` is created from an existing `tag` and exposes release notes and links to download the software or source code from GitHub.

> Using GitHub's API, I can't get the releases list, but I can get the tags list.

The current version of the **[GitHub API](http://developer.github.com/v3/)** doesn't expose a way to manage `Release`s (create, update, ...). I'm pretty sure that this shouldn't take too long before it's exposed.

However, it's currently possible to list the releases and tags of a specific repository.

For instance, the url below will list the **6 releases** (as of today) from **[ReactiveUI](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI)**

- https://api.github.com/repos/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/releases

Whereas this one will list the **54 tags** (as of today) from the same repository

- https://api.github.com/repos/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/tags

Creating a release is *currently* in a process which involves a manual action (adding the release notes, uploading the packages, ...). This explains why `tag`s are not transparently seen as `Release`s.

---

If you want to be notified of the API changes, you can subscribe to **[the GitHub API Changes blog](http://developer.github.com/changes/)**.

However, if you can't wait, the GitHub API home page states *"If you have any problems or requests please contact support.*". This can be done through an email to **support@github.com** or this **[contact form](https://github.com/contact?form%5Bsubject%5D=APIv3)**.

### Update:

The GitHub API now allows to manipulate `Release`s. See the **[announcement](https://github.blog/2013-09-25-releases-api-preview/)**.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. Re: /releases - I get [0 releases for rails](https://api.github.com/repos/rails/rails/releases), which it a bit weird, no?

Comment: I don't think it's weird. That only means that the Rails team hasn't used the GitHub UI to create a `Release` from an existing `tag`. `Release`s are quite a recent addition. Maybe do the Rails team prefer to stick with their current process and post to their blog whenever a new version is released (see **[3.2.14 announcement](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2013/7/23/Rails-3-2-14-has-been-released/)**).

Comment: +1 for the clear distinction between a tag and a release and what each is for: "A `tag` is a **git** concept whereas a `Release` is **GitHub** higher level concept ... A `Release` is created from an existing `tag` and exposes release notes and links to download the software or source code from GitHub."

Comment: It might also worthwhile to know that there's now a command-line tool called [hub](https://github.com/github/hub) that supercharges the capabilities of git. Among these superpowers, there's the ability to push release in the terminal.

Comment: It seems that until you create your first release in GitHub, all of your tags show up under Releases. I find this needlessly confusing.