# get releases empty in github api

Tags: api, github

I try to get idea-community releases with following, but it return empty

```
curl "https://api.github.com/repos/JetBrains/intellij-community/releases"
```

but when the releases is exist in [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/releases)

how to get its releases

Answer (score 8):

From [the documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/):

> This returns a list of releases, which does not include regular Git tags that have not been associated with a release. To get a list of Git tags, use the [Repository Tags API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-tags).

GitHub's UI is confusing, but this repository doesn't actually have any releases, which are a GitHub-specific concept. The "releases" you are seeing are actually just regular Git tags.

Try this instead:

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/JetBrains/intellij-community/tags
```

See also [What's the difference between tag and release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18506508/whats-the-difference-between-tag-and-release)

Comment: If a repo doesn't have any releases defined, GitHub's UI will list all tags as if they were releases. But the GitHub API doesn't do that; releases have to be explicitly defined to show up in the API.