# Downloading latest git/git release from github

Tags: github-api

How do I download the latest release source for [git/git from github](https://github.com/git/git/releases)?

Normal way, according to api docs, should be to get https://api.github.com/repos/git/git/releases/latest and get URLs from there. However:

```
$ curl https://api.github.com/repos/git/git/releases/latest
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#get-the-latest-release"
}

$ curl https://api.github.com/repos/git/git/releases
[

]
```

Other projects work fine:

```
$ curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/aria2/aria2/releases/latest | jq .tarball_url
"https://api.github.com/repos/aria2/aria2/tarball/release-1.35.0"
```

Comment: git/git is only read mirror repository, maybe thats why

Comment: Upon closer inspection perhaps this is the case as described here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/35062729/7034621

Comment: Yup, [Xamarin.Forms](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/releases) do have releases, see difference in [UI rendered](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/releases)

Comment: @orhtej2 yep tags are there, thx