# How do I find the version of a go package

Tags: go, dependencies, version

I'm using [dep](https://github.com/golang/dep) and I want to add new dependencies in the `Gopkg.toml` file but I don't how to find the correct version.

I see that someone already added a dependency to [`fatih/color`](http://github.com/fatih/color) from github and specified version `1.5.0`. How was this value found?

For example I'm adding a dependency on [`pkg/errors`](https://github.com/pkg/errors), what is it's current version?

Answer (score -1):

I'm an idiot, missed the `releases` link...

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It uses the git tags, not GitHub releases.

Comment: @Adrian GitHub releases [*are* git tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18506508/whats-the-difference-between-tag-and-release). Not all tags are releases, but all releases have a corresponding tag.

Comment: Yes. It still uses git tags though, not GitHub releases.