# How to view code in a Github repository as of a specific release?

Tags: git, github, repository, airflow, release

I would like to see what the code in a whole repository looks like of a specific release. As an example, I'd like to view the code for Apache Airflow as of version 1.10.6.

I can find the summary of the release here, but don't know how to get to the associated code as of this release: https://github.com/apache/airflow/releases/tag/1.10.6rc1

Maybe it's possible to do this locally even (although I don't think git itself has the concept of a "release")?

Does what I'm trying to do make sense?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The circled link should take you to that particular snapshot of the code.

[image: https://github.com/apache/airflow/releases/tag/1.10.6rc1]

Answer (score 4):

Every GitHub release is associated with a git tag. The tag you are looking for can be seen in the release URL. For example, the URL in your question, `https://github.com/apache/airflow/releases/tag/1.10.6rc1`, corresponds to the tag `1.10.6rc1`.

To checkout to a tag locally, all you need is:

```
git checkout <tag-name>
```

In the given example,

```
git checkout 1.10.6rc1
```

For more information, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18506508/5987698) discusses the difference between a git tag and a GitHub release. You can read more about git tags in the [official documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) of git.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way follow these clicks

[image]